# Screenshot_1.png: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, yii2, виджет

Установил на yii2 basic виджет `kartik fileInput`. Форма добавления изображений отображается корректно, но после нажатия на "загрузить" выходит вот такая ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Вот код.

```
<?php
    echo FileInput::widget([
        'name' => 'UploadFile[imageFiles][]',
        'language' => 'ru',
        'options' => ['multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => ['previewFileType' => 'any', 'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/images/site_images']),]
    ]);
?>
```

Может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Собственно, и какая ошибка?)

Comment: Извиняюсь, указал только в названии вопроса. вот ошибка:
Screenshot_1.png: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: так не пойдет. Нужен ПОЛНЫЙ текст ошибки с указанием на то, где он ругается. И код, на котором эта ошибка вываливается полностью.... Скриншот вы так и не приложили. Потому, что по `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` можно лишь дать вам ответ - что у вас синтаксическая ошибка в коде

Comment: К сожалению больше он ничего не дает. прикладывать скрины я не умею, вот ссылка.http://prntscr.com/9s04ij

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это вроде и есть полный текст ошибки? `eval("<!doctype html>")`

Comment: @Qwertiy Просто обычно в таких случаях пишется где в коде ошибка, на какой строке и в каком месте кода, а не просто `у вас ошибка`.

Answer (score 1):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Скорее всего, пытаешься в качестве скрипта исполнить html-страницу. Это может происходить из-за ajax-запроса к текущему url при указании неправильного content-type или явном требовании к jquery получить скрипт.

По крайней мере, это наиболее распространённая причина такой ошибки.

Comment: я думал что в 'uploadUrl' нужно просто указать директорию для загрузки картинок. Получается что нужно указать URL контроллера, в котором буду происходить все действия?

Comment: @Анатолий да, именно так. в контроллере вы должны будете реализовать логику сохранения туда, куда вам необходимо и произвести вам необходимые действия. а `uploadUrl` - контроллер/экшн